# A measure of correlation between two finite strings of bits

Tags: combinatorics

Given two bit strings $S_1$ and $S_2$ of lengths $n_1,n_2$, I am interested in a function of these two strings called $f(S_1, S_2)$. Here is the definition of this function:

To compute $f(S_1, S_2)$, form the string $U_1$ of length $N=\operatorname{lcm}(n_1,n_2)$ by placing $N/n_1$ copies of $S_1$ end-to-end. Then, form the string $U_2$ of length $N=\operatorname{lcm}(n_1,n_2)$ by placing $N/n_2$ copies of $S_2$ end-to-end. Then, $f(S_1, S_2)$ is the number of positions where $U_1$ and $U_2$ both have a one.

For example:

$$S_1=1011 $$
$$S_2=101 $$
Then, $U_1 = 101101101101, U_2 = 101110111011$ and $f(S_1,S_2)=6$.
My question is:

Does this function $f(S_1, S_2)$ have a name? Does it appear anywhere in the mathematical literature?

Comment: This seems extremely sensitive to length in a weird way, e.g. if you start with two strings of length $n, 2n$ then their lcm is $2n$ and then adding a single bit to the second string produces a much larger lcm of $n(2n+1)$. Do you really want this? Why not normalize by the lcm? (Even this I think is weird but a bit less weird.) In any case, for strings of the *same* length this is essentially the Hamming distance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance

Comment: I think this may be better thought of as Hamming distance between periodic boolean functions of the same length. Although, the difference between XOR and AND is probably important. It's not quite Hamming distance.

Comment: Ah, you're right, it's not quite the Hamming distance. If you wanted to think about periodic sequences then I would definitely normalize by the lcm if I were you. Do you have any particular application in mind?

Comment: In my situation, the two strings are "truth tables" of two properties. I'm trying to understand the set of places where both property A and property B are true.